# chosen jquery not working dynamic html options

Tags: jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I have two select dropdowns,
When i change first select, onchange function will execute but options not updated in chosen 2nd dropdown. But options populated in orginal select.

Onchange function generate dynamic options for second select, when i inspect element original select updated, chosen results area not updated.

I follow below code.

```
 <select id="account" onchange="changePackage()">
 <select id="package">


  javascript
  $(select).chosen();

   $("#account"). on('change',function(){
    $("#package").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: Data  binding is working, but it takes to much time, when i place  code like  this
function changePackage(){
          var value = changePackageChosen();
          if(value == true){

          setTimeout(function(){
  $("#package").trigger('chosen:updated');
},15000);
}
}

function changePackageChosen(){
/* binding options*/
return true;
}

And search also not working for dynamic html content(Like jsp foreach options).
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").chosen();
});

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should help you. You just need to add the callback function which will be executed after the select is updated:

```
function changePackage(){
    changePackageChosen(function(success) {
        if(success) {
            $("#package").trigger('chosen:updated');
        }
    });
}

function changePackageChosen(callback){
    /* binding options*/
    callback(true);
}
```